# Finding space to solve direct sum equation

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

I know if I have the following equation

$$
\mathbb{R}^3=\text{span} \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right\} \oplus W
$$

Then $W=\text{span} \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$ as it has to *span over the last entry*.

How do I find a suitable space for $W$ in the following

$$
\mathbb{R}^3=\text{span} \left\{ 
\begin{bmatrix}0\\ \frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{5}{3\sqrt{5}}\\ \frac{2}{3\sqrt{5}} \\ \frac{4}{3\sqrt{5}} \end{bmatrix}
\right\} \oplus W
$$

would it be $\text{span} \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ \frac{5}{3\sqrt{5}} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$ so that the sum of the entries is $\frac{5}{3\sqrt{5}}$?

Comment: "Then $W=\text{span} \{ \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\}$ as it has to *span over the last entry*." This is an extremely common incorrect misconception. $W$ can also be $\operatorname{span} \left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$, etc

Comment: @NinadMunshi yes my bad. I meant a suitable value for $W$ is this, rather than this is the only value for $W$

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, calling the span vectors $b_1$ an $b_2$, respectively, notice that

$$b_1+3b_2 = \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{5} \\ 0 \\ \sqrt{5} \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$3b_2 -4b_1 = \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{5} \\ 2\sqrt{5} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

thus the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ is not in the span of $b_1$ and $b_2$. So one choice of $W$ you can make is

$$W = \operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

Comment: Nice! Is there a systematic method for calculating the coefficients of $b_i$ / where did they come from? Is there a way to represent it as a RREF problem?